# calculating sum and subtraction of table row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to calculate `sum of all columns`, and `subtraction of col1 and col2` only, i found few examples online to add row data but how i can perform both action on one row. using class or id name.

```
<table id="sum_table" width="450" border="1">

  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>column one</th>
      <th >column two</th>
      <th >column three</th>
      <th >sum of all columns</th>
      <th >subtraction</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td class="col1">1</td>
      <td class="col2">2</td>
      <td class="col3">3</td>
    <td><span class="sum"></span> </td>
    <td><span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

       <td class="col1">43</td>
      <td class="col2">432</td>
      <td class="col3">33</td>
      <td> <span class="sum"></span> </td>
       <td> <span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="calculate" onclick = "calculate()">calculate</button>
```

**jquery:**

```
function calculate(){
var col1=$('.col1').text();
var col2=$('.col2').text();
var col3=$('.col3').text();
var sum= col1+col2+col3;
var subtract= col1-col2;
$(".sum").text(sum);
$(".subtract").text(subtract);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattii/9qazhm2c/19/)

Comment: You want to calculate column value?

Comment: yes var sum= col1+col2+col3;
var subtract= col1-col2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the `table tr` and use `.find()` on the columns you need. I added `.col` on each of the value columns so we won't need to specify the three columns on addition.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum;
  var difference;
  $("tbody tr").each(function() {
    sum = 0;
    difference = 0;

    $(this).find(".col").each(function() {
      // console.log($(this).html());
      sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
    });

    difference = parseFloat($(this).find(".col1").html()) - parseFloat($(this).find(".col2").html());

    $(this).find(".sum").html(sum);
    $(this).find(".subtract").html(difference);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" width="450" border="1">

  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>column one</th>
      <th>column two</th>
      <th>column three</th>
      <th>sum of all columns</th>
      <th>subtraction</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td class="col col1">1</td>
      <td class="col col2">2</td>
      <td class="col col3">3</td>
      <td><span class="sum"></span> </td>
      <td><span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td class="col col1">43</td>
      <td class="col col2">432</td>
      <td class="col col3">33</td>
      <td> <span class="sum"></span> </td>
      <td> <span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="calculate" onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
```

Here's the answer using input fields;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calculate").on("click", function() {

    var sum;
    var difference;
    $("tbody tr").each(function() {
      sum = 0;
      difference = 0;

      $(this).find(".col").each(function() {
        // console.log($(this).html());
        sum += parseFloat($(this).find("input").val());
      });

      difference = parseFloat($(this).find(".col1").find("input").val()) - parseFloat($(this).find(".col2").find("input").val());

      $(this).find(".sum").html(sum);
      $(this).find(".subtract").html(difference);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" width="450" border="1">

  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>column one</th>
      <th>column two</th>
      <th>column three</th>
      <th>sum of all columns</th>
      <th>subtraction</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td class="col col1"><input value="1" /></td>
      <td class="col col2"><input value="2" /></td>
      <td class="col col3"><input value="3" /></td>
      <td><span class="sum"></span> </td>
      <td><span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td class="col col1"><input value="43" /></td>
      <td class="col col2"><input value="432" /></td>
      <td class="col col3"><input value="33" /></td>
      <td> <span class="sum"></span> </td>
      <td> <span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="calculate">Sum
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not working on js fiddle, can you please check

Comment: @Fayakon It's not working on your fiddle because `onclick=""` cannot find the `calculate()` function. Here's the updated fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/eqam4k7h/1/

In this fiddle, we used assigned an click event handler to the button using `.on("click")` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, jerdine sabio, just last comment please, if i want to make text box of any column will it still calculate when i press button.

Comment: @Fayakon no, it wouldn't work because to access the td's we're using `.html()`.  Here's a new fiddle using input fields. In here we are using `.val()` to access the value attribute of form fields. http://jsfiddle.net/n53tw2va/

Comment: that's awesome way to do it thank you, just curious what if one column is not input field, can we pass both, .html and .value?

Comment: @Fayakon Here's a new fiddle, I added null checks to determine if we should use .val() or .html(); http://jsfiddle.net/f78xedpk/

Comment: Thank you, you are most cooperative person i found here.

Comment: @Fayakon you're welcome. it's just that I'm at work and there's nothing else to do haha! Thanks too!

Comment: when i leave text box empty it's not showing anything :(

Comment: @Fayakon Added a null check again to check if the input field has an empty value, if it does, assign 0; http://jsfiddle.net/wcdbtn7a/

Comment: hello again, sorry for disturbing you, can you please tell me how i can subtract column1 and column2 only, when i keyup on column1 input.

Comment: @Fayakon http://jsfiddle.net/ecxzmg85/ here you go. I added a new on keyup handler for col1 input field which will find the values of col1 and col2 and subtract.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this working example.

```js
var col1=0,col2=0,col3=0,sum=0,subtract=0;
function calculate(){
$(".jsTableBody tr").each(function(){
col1=$(this).find('.col1').text();
col2=$(this).find('.col2').text();
col3=$(this).find('.col3').text();
sum= parseInt(col1) + parseInt(col2)+ parseInt(col3);
console.log(sum);
subtract= parseInt(col1)-parseInt(col2);
$(this).find(".sum").html(sum);
$(this).find(".subtract").html(subtract);
})

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" width="450" border="1">

  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>column one</th>
      <th >column two</th>
      <th >column three</th>
      <th >sum of all columns</th>
      <th >subtraction</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="jsTableBody">
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">1</td>
      <td class="col2">2</td>
      <td class="col3">3</td>
    <td><span class="sum"></span> </td>
    <td><span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

       <td class="col1">43</td>
      <td class="col2">432</td>
      <td class="col3">33</td>
      <td> <span class="sum"></span> </td>
       <td> <span class="subtract"></span> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="calculate" onclick = "calculate()">calculate</button>
```